# How to get following-sibling or child of HTML with xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, screen-scraping

I have some HTML I'm trying to scrape. Tring to learn Selenium. What I need is the words Fashion, and Long, and so on.
I've tried:

```
 style = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[text()='Style:']/following::strong").text

 style = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[text()='Style:']/following-sibling::strong").text

 style = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[contains(.,'Style:')] /preceding-sibling::strong").text
```

and everything in between.

```
 <div class="xxkkk20">
 <strong>Style:</strong> Fashion <br>             
 <strong>Shirt Length:</strong> Long <br>
 <strong>Collar:</strong> Scoop Neck <br>
 <strong>Material:</strong> Polyester <br>  
 <strong>Pattern Type:</strong> Floral,Skulls <br>
 <strong>Embellishment:</strong> Lace <br>
 <strong>Thickness:</strong> Standard <br>
 <strong>Fabric Stretch:</strong> High Stretch <br>
 <strong>Seasons:</strong> Summer <br>
 <strong>Weight:</strong> 0.1700kg <br>
 <strong>Package Contents:</strong> 1 x Tank Top         
 </div>
```

Comment: I played with a little more with the help of the board and came up with this:                 material = [material]
print(material)                                                                                                                                      This is the output I got:   ['Style: Fashion\nShirt Length: Long\nCollar: Scoop Neck\nMaterial: Polyester\nPattern Type: Floral,Skulls\nEmbellishment: Lace\nThickness: Standard\nFabric Stretch: High Stretch\nSeasons: Summer\nWeight: 0.1700kg\nPackage Contents: 1 x Tank Top']

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of them in a list like given below and iterate them over the list to get all the web element and finally apply text method to extract text.

```
all_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='xxkkk20']/strong")
for ele in all_elements:
   print(ele.text)
```

**Update 1 :**

```
keys = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//strong")
for key in keys: 
  print(key.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

Comment: That just printed the keys. I need what follows the keys each by themself. Thanks.

Comment: @tejas : Check out the Update1 section

Answer (score 0):

```
pairs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xxkkk20"]').text.split("\n")
for pair in pairs:
    texts = pair.split()
    print(texts[1])
```

Explanation:
First you get all the texts inside the parent `div` element.
Then you split it by `\n` according to `<br>` elements there.
Now you should actually have pairs of texts like `Style: Fashion`.
And since you want to get the second values only you need to split each pair and get the second substring.
I suggest there is a space there between the first and the second texts in the pairs strings.
In case there is no spaces there, you still can split it finally by `:` so it will look like this:

```
pairs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xxkkk20"]')text.split("\n")
for pair in pairs:
    texts = pair.split(":")
    print(texts[1])
```

Comment: I could not get the text.split("\n") it gave me a attribute errion

Comment: what do you see in `pairs` after `pairs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xxkkk20"]').text` ? without the `.split("\n")`

Comment: if it is `null` maybe you are missing some wait / delay or the element is inside an iframe?

Comment: I get: IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: No, I'm asking: if you do this: `pairs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xxkkk20"]').text` what is the content of `pairs` variable? `pairs` should contain the entire texts inside the parent `div` element

Comment: This what I get:                                                                                                         
Style: Fashion
Shirt Length: Long
Collar: Scoop Neck
Material: Polyester
Pattern Type: Floral,Skulls
Embellishment: Lace
Thickness: Standard
Fabric Stretch: High Stretch
Seasons: Summer
Weight: 0.1700kg
Package Contents: 1 x Tank Top

Comment: Can you tell me what is between the `Style: Fashion` and `Shirt Length: Long` etc? It should be a new line sign there. Is it?

Comment: Between fashion and shirt there is \n.   {'Style: Fashion\nShirt Length: Long\nCollar: Scoop Neck\n}

Comment: So, it should work.. What if you first get the texts with `pairs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="xxkkk20"]').text`. As we know, this gives all the texts as it should, and now do this: `pairs=pairs.split("\n")`? This should give as a list or strings like `[[Style: Fashion],[Shirt Length: Long],[Collar: Scoop Neck] ...]` correct?

Comment: material = dict(m.split(': ') for m in list(material)[0].splitlines())    Gets me     {'Style': 'Fashion', 'Shirt Length': 'Long', 'Collar': 'Scoop Neck'}  So between Fashion and Shirt I get a ,

Comment: What are you trying to say me? Is it work now?

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks to everyone that help me, now on to the next project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
textValues = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="xxkkk20"]')text.split("\n")
for txt in textValues:
    print(txt.split(":")[1].strip())
```